# Extracting or selecting the first two numbers of a cell

Tags: excel

I want to select the first two numbers in a cell and put them in a new column, while keeping the original cell in tact. The table below shows what the extract *should* look like and what the original number is.

```
  Extract   Number   
 --------- --------- 
       00   0000852  
       01   0163457  
       92   9287514
```

I have tried using this function:

```
=LEFT(B2,2)
```

The problem is that the function returns an extract like:

```
  Extract   Number   
 --------- --------- 
       85   0000852  
       16   0163457  
       92   9287514
```

which is excluding the preliminary zeros.

Comment: Are the number using a number format to show the extra 0s?

Comment: a Custom format with 14 zeros, because it was the only way I could think of to get them to show.

Comment: Then the number being saved and used by excel is the one without the 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying a number format does not change the underlying value of the cell, it only changes how the number is displayed in that cell:

[image]

Even though it shows `0000852` the number stored is `852` and thus when the Left is used it references the stored not the displayed number.

You will need to use TEXT to add the leading 0s as the number stored does not have them, they are being shown by a custom number format:

```
=LEFT(TEXT(B2,"0000000"),2)
```

[image]